# Does not contain a definition for 'BinDataGridView' Y boton de borrar

Tags: c#

Estoy queriendo pasar datos a un gridview que tengo en la interfaz llamado  dataGridView1

Pero en el botón de agregar me da error en el evento BindDataGridView, me pueden dar una orientación sobre la solución

```
private void btnAgregr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var rowsChecked = this.DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));


        foreach (DataRow rowOrigen in rowsChecked)
        {
            DataRow rowDestino = this.DataTableSection.NewRow();
            rowDestino["Sel"] = false;
            rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"];
            rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
            this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
        }
        this.dataGridView1.BindDataGridView(this.DataTableSection);
    }
```

Boton de quitar:

Para eliminar las filas de los checkbox seleccionados tengo este codigo
     private void BtnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar una fila del grid");
            return;
        }

        var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            var row = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["Id"] == item.Cells["Id"].Value);
            if (row != null)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(row);
            }

        }
```

*Boton de quitar no hace nada (aunque tiene codigo)*
*Es winform en c#*
De ante mano, gracias

Comment: ¿`BindDataGridView` es un método?. Por favor [edit] la pregunta: ¿qué tipo de aplicación está desarrollando?, ¿Winforms, ASP.NET?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se de donde sacas el `BindDataGridView` pero este no existe, deberias usar

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataTableSection;
```

con el `DataSource` asignas los datos al grid

[DataGridView.DataSource Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-3.5)

Comment: Si, me funciona, ahora el punto es para quitar los datos seleccionados, no me funciona, tengo esto en el boton de quitar 
(lo edite en el codigo principal de arriba)

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo y ejecuta paso a paso, puedes validar que encuentra la row ingresando en el if?

Comment: Ya lo logre amigo muchas gracias utilice el codigo

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(item);
            }
            dataGridView1.Refresh();

        }`